# Does the beta negative binomial (BNB) distribution have a conjugate prior?

Tags: prior, negative-binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, conjugate-prior, map-estimation

BNB distribution is constructed using negative binomial and beta distributions, which are both exponential family, so my guess would be yes, there shoudl exist a conjugate prior in theory. But what is it? I could not find it in any resources and I am not confident enough to try to derive it myself. There is likely no explicit formula, but that's perhaps not a huge problem as I would be quite happy with even approximate (numerically calculated) solutions. My goal is to use the posterior for MAP estimation of the BNB parameters.

Comment: Hi! Can you write down the pmf or provide some reference to BNB?

Comment: Which parameter of the beta-negative-binomial do you intend to estimate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the BNB distribution does not belong to an exponential family and it does not admit a tractable conjugate prior. It does not even have a tractable moment generating function and it only has a limited number of finite moments. See Wang (2011).

The BNB distribution is a beta mixture of negative binomial distributions. Being constructed from exponential family distributions in this way does not in any way imply that it will inherit theoretical properties of exponential family distributions.

**Reference**

Wang Z (2011).
One mixed negative binomial distribution with application.
*Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference*.
141 (3), 1153-1160.

Comment: That's bad news, but thanks for the reference!

Comment: @user1747134 It's your research and your decision of course but, if one of my students proposed what you're doing, I would question the wisdom of the approach. The NB is a gamma mixture of Poissons. The BNB is a beta mixture of NBs. You propose a prior on BNB, so the posterior will be a mixture of a mixture of a mixture. Do you really need that many levels? The BNB is over-parametrized so you need to place a constraint on the parameters before you can even get started. You need some strong motivation for which constraint you will impose, otherwise any results will very hard to interpret.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I understand where you're coming from. I am working on a problem where I have a collection of datasets which I think I can reasonably assume to come from the same family of distributions, but apparently with distinct parametrization for each dataset. Empirically, the BNB distribution seemed to match the data quite well. Why? I am not sure, as you say it's hard to interpret at this point. Perhaps another distribution family would be better, but I certainly need something discrete with infinite support and heavy tail.